# the first input block after a post request. cakephp

Tags: forms, cakephp, submit, block

I have a little problem with a form in cakephp. When the view render the first time I can introduce info in all the inputs but after a submit if a validation fail the first input blocks, I can't introduce more info in there but in the rest I can. here is the view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('phone');
echo $this->Form->input('complete_name');
echo $this->Form->input('adress');
echo $this->Form->input('state');
echo $this->Form->input('city');
echo $this->Form->input('zip_code');
echo $this->Form->button('Save', array('name' =>'save'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

In the controller:

```
public function user_info(){
if($this->request->is('post'))
{
    if($this->User->save($this->request->data))
    {
      $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'user_store'));
    }
    else
    {
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('problem saving'), 'flash_bad');
    }
}
```

Validations of the model:

```
public $validate = array(
  'complete_name' => array(
     'notempty' => array(
       'rule' => array('custom','/^[a-z A-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑäëïöüÄËÏÖÜ]{5,}$/i'),
       'message' => 'fail the name'
     ),
     'maxlength' => array(
        'rule' => array('maxlength', 45)
     )
    ),      

  'adress' => array(
      'notempty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notempty'),
        'message' => 'fail adress',
        ),
      'maxlength' => array(
        'rule' => array('maxlength', 60),
        ),
      'minlength' => array(
        'rule' => array('minlength', 10),
        'message' => 'fail adress'
        )
    ),

  'state' => array(
      'notempty' => array(
        'rule' => array('custom', '/^[a-z A-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑäëïöüÄËÏÖÜ]{5,}$/i'),
        'message' => 'fail state'
        ),
      'maxlength' => array(
        'rule' => array('maxlength', 30)
        )
    ),

  'city' => array(
     'notempty' => array(
       'rule' => array('custom', '/^[a-z A-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑäëïöüÄËÏÖÜ]{5,}$/i'),
       'message' => 'fail city'
        ),
     'maxlength' => array(
        'rule' => array('maxlength', 30)
        )
    ),

  'zip_code' => array(
     'notempty' => array(
        'rule' => '/^[1-9]{4,4}$/i',
        'message' => 'fail zip code'
        )
    )
);
```

when a validation fail I can see the message in the view and the session flash too and I can edit everything except the phone. if I exchange lines in the view code like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('complete_name'); // change position with phone
echo $this->Form->input('phone');
echo $this->Form->input('adress');
echo $this->Form->input('state');
echo $this->Form->input('city');
echo $this->Form->input('zip_code');
echo $this->Form->button('Save', array('name' =>'save'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Then I can't edit complete_name. someone know what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you describe, I think css or jQuery is placing a `div` that extends to that input preventing you from editing it, perhaps a `div` with an `error` class or even padding on that first input can cause issues. Regardless, use a developer tool like Firebug in Firefox to investigate. You will be able to see whether that is what is happening.